# ListView remove space between ListTile

Tags: flutter

I am trying to remove empty space between ListTile in a ListView

[The list i am trying to delete space from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcVM3.png)

What i tried so far :
Remove padding of ListView
Remove padding of ListTile
Remove any space from the ListTile content.

I know it is probably that i dont understand where that free space come from. Any idea ?

```
    Widget buildWidget() {
    List<ListItem> listData = createListData();

    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        itemCount: listData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = listData[index];
          return ListTile(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            title: item.buildTitle(context),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

EDIT Solved : ListTile force padding. So even if the answer work if you're force to use a ListTile. Basicly using a Container instead of ListTile make it work without that strange fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `dense: true`, so:

```
ListTile(
    dense: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
)
```

Comment: Tried that earlier. Doesn't work.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try visual density

Comment: Thanks you. Look like a strange fix tho. Any idea why flutter basic behaviour is to force padding between item ?
I am will look into visualDensity doc tho. Thx you.

Comment: That's because we used a list tile.  You can return a container and add items in a row with no padding instead

Comment: That a better explanation i dont know why i didnt try without ListTile. Thank you !